# How to get sas datetime in this format 2023-07-19 00:00:00 from this 19JUL2023:00:00:00

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Hi I need to datetime in **2023-07-19 00:00:00** format from this 19JUL2023:00:00:00

```
data _null_;
    from_batch_dttm = intnx('minutes', dhms(datepart(1958774400), int(27/4), mod(27,4)*15, 0), -15 * 192);
Call symput('from_batch_dttm_orcl', strip(put(from_batch_dttm, datetime22.)));

run;
```

Comment: Need it for what exactly? In a printout?  You mention SAS Macro, are you planning to place the value into a macro variable?  What will you do with the macro variable?

Comment: Where do you have the datetime value now? Is it in a variable in a dataset? Is it a numeric or character variable?

Comment: What part of that code is the INPUT and what part is the OUTPUT?  You seem to be trying to generate a macro variable with a string in the style generated by the DATETIME format?  What do you plan to DO with the macro variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works for you

```
data _null_;
    sDateTime = input("19JUL2023:00:00:00", datetime22.);
    fDateTime = put(sDateTime, datetime21.); /* Use datetime21. format if you want */
    
    format sDateTime datetime22.; /* Specify the desired format for sDateTime */
    
    /* Print Results */
    put "Datetime Supplied : " "19JUL2023:00:00:00";
    put "Formatted Datetime: " fDateTime;
run;
```

If it does work for you then Do not Forge to Flag it **Accepted** and **Clicking** the Green Tick mark